# Force alpha and numeric into a field with a hyphen separator

Tags: html

Please take a look at following image

http://i50.tinypic.com/2cohfeo.jpg

I want help in inserting the code for the 4 characteristics in the image and thus forming the new html code

Comment: [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Not exactly what you need but using html5 you can: <input type="text" pattern="[A-Z]{5}-[0-9]{5}" placeholder="ALPHA-NUMBR" />

Comment: There is a jquery plugin, http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/, to do the watermark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using javascript and jquery (if youre using regular javascript, I think you need to use getElementById, Google it) and assuming your textbox is named "text":

http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

```
$('input[name=text]').keydown(function(event)
{
    var text = this.val().replace("-",""); //get current text, take out the -
    var strlength = text.length;

    if (strlength >=10) //reached max length, ignore character        
    {
        return false; // might be event.preventDefault();
    }
    else if (strlength<5) //you want a letter
    {
        //if not a letter, cancel input
        if (!(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(String.fromCharCode(event.which))) return false;
    }
    else if (strlength>=5) //you want a letter
    {
        //if not a number, cancel input
        if (!(/^[0-9]+$/.test(String.fromCharCode(event.which))) return false;
        else if (strlength==5) this.val(text + "-"); //Add the hyphen
    }
});
```

May need code to handle the backspace, but should be self-evident/explanatory